# C2663: 'std::_Tree>::insert': 5 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, set, visual-c++-2017

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
map <string, set<pair<int, set<int>>>> dictonary;

int s()
{
    for (auto & i : dictonary["abc"])
    {
        i.second.insert(2);  //error C2663
    }
}
```

> C2663: 'std::_Tree>::insert': 5 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer.

`i.second` is considered by the compiler `const` qualified so that insertion is forbidden.

If it is not a bug, how can I manipulate it?

Comment: `std::set` iterators only allow `const` access. If you were able to modify the `set` as you iterated over it, it would be possible to affect its ordering.

Comment: You need to remove that item from the set and insert a new item with the updated values.  The set needs to rebuild itself -- you can't just go fiddle around with the set's internals.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is not a bug, how can I manipulate it?

You cannot change value that is already inserted into `std::set` in place as data is ordered and modification would invalidate the invariant. You either need to remove/modify/reinsert or use different container than `std::set`